# Pyspark proper skew data salting technique example code

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have following dataframes

```
deptDf.columns
['deptid', 'name', 'dept', 'deptid']

empDf.columns
['eid', 'ename', 'deptid','esal']

if do the join on based on the deptid

deptDf.join(empDf, deptDf.deptid == empDf.deptid, 'inner')
```

few depts have few no of employees where few depts have huge no of employees , here so data is skewed.

To overcode data skew issue i want to use data salting technique, Could you please someone provide the code for it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one (you can break it down into more than 10 parts, depends on your table really):

```py
bigger_tabs = bigger.randomSplit([1.0] * 10)
for i in range(len(bigger_tabs)):
    bigger_tabs[i]=bigger_tabs[i].join(smaller, COND, JOIN_TYPE)
final_tab=bigger_tabs[0]
for i in range(1,len(bigger_tabs)):
    final_tab=final_tab.union(bigger_tabs[i])
```

Comment: Thanks , can you give me random number generate solution also. i.e  key+randomnumber one

Comment: @AnubeigMogal ```randomSplit``` does exactly that - it splits randomly with weights. It's just implicit.

Comment: Ok thanks @Grzegorz Skibinski , i will try this and let you know the result